# Avoiding MySQL1044 error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1044

I am trying to learn PHP and MySQL and while I reached a chapter on MySQL I was asked to create a database using this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE publications;
```

After I typed it in the mysql console I got this error:

> ERROR 1044(42000):Access denied for user ''@localhost' to database 'root'

I am already logged in to my administrator account so I think the privileges should't be a problem.I have installed with the XAMPP package.

How can this be solved?

Comment: There is no PHP code I used the mysql command line to do this it is what it said in the book "Learning PHP , MySql and Javascript by Robin Nixon

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that you upgraded your version of EasyPHP or you did something to disable the root password. If that is the case, you should try reestablishing a password for root. Had the same problem and that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://localhost/xampp/ and set the appropriate passwords (in Security tab). If you use `mysql` client program, make sure you call it with appropriate credentials: `mysql -u <username> -p <password>`. Username will mostly be `root`  until you create some new accounts.

Then I suggest you use phpMyAdmin for experimenting with MySQL (it should be at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ )

Comment: I have tryed typing exactly what you said and  now I am geting an error 1064

Comment: Since you said the same for BluesRockAddict's answer, you should explain what you DID exactly.

Comment: I have tryed typing in mysql -u root -p pass ,mysql -u root,mysqladmin -u root -p pass ,even exactly the versions you 2 provided mysql -u <username> -p <password> , mysqladmin -u root password [mypassword] letter by letter with my user and pass and I always get -> if I type ';' II get ERROR 1064 something about error in syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is getting a little confused - let me try to answer this.

Mysqladmin is a command line client for administering your mysql database system - you normally don't need to run it once you have mysql working. The shell command line interface to the mysql server is `mysql`. (If you don't know how to run a shell command line, that's another problem. Also, if you're on Windows, say so, since that has its own challenges.) The arguments are:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword databasename
```

if you are running this command on the same server as mysql. Note the lack of space after the -p - that is important.

So, type the above line to invoke the command line interface to mysql. Then you can type your mysql commands. Things like `show tables`, `desc tablename`, etc., will work. That is they will work unless you have an authentication problem. But you will know you have an authentication problem because when you tried to run `mysql` as above, it will fail with some error, like "Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)". This is a nice descriptive error message that points you exactly where the problem is.

Does that help?

You can go back to using xampp or anything else once you've made sure that you know the right parameters by checking with the command line. (Always check with the command line when strangeness happens - it's so much easier than trying to debug through other interfaces.)